# How to display whitespace characters in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2

I'd like to be able to see the whitespace characters used in files that I edit with Sublime Text 2 so that I can see when a tab is used instead of a space and replace that just to provide one example.

Comment: Coincidentally, all you should need to do is select text with the cursor to reveal whitespace characters.

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your User preferences:

```
"draw_white_space": "all"
```

Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297068/sublime-text-2-how-to-change-white-space-characters-color

Comment: Any way to also show newline/carriage-return etc?

Comment: I doubt it, I think Sublime just shows spaces and tabs.